# how to use riverpod, by combing futureprovider with stateprovider?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am using futureprovider for getting response from api , but i want get the list from api and assign it to the stateprovider by using listprovider.state="data from api" , how to will it work ,
how to combine future provdier with the state provider .

Comment: Hello! This question is unclear to me. Why are you trying to assign the result of the FutureProvider to a SateProvider? You should be able to read the FutureProvider directly. There should be no need to use the StateProvider here. Am I missing something?

Comment: i have added a search bar at the top of list so when i get the result ,i want to query the list, i want to change the state of the list according to the search data while quering the list so that's why i want to use stateprovider is it possible by using only futureprovider?

Comment: is there any package which can help me to open my app automatically on boot of the device

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATED ANSWER

After a discussion with [@31Carlton7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14574348/31carlton7), he's opened [an issue on github](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/2078#event-8247226641), and after a discussion with [Remi Rousselet](https://github.com/rrousselGit) (the creator of riverpod) we've reached a better solution for this problem.

[(from the final solution on the issue)](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/2078#issuecomment-1380969200)

Running the app:

**main.dart**

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Creating the foo class and provider:

**foo.dart**

```dart
part 'foo.g.dart';

class Foo {
  final int bar;
  int? baz;

  Foo(
    this.bar, {
    this.baz,
  });
}

@riverpod
class FooController extends _$FooController {
  FooController(this.foo);

  Foo foo;

  @override
  FutureOr<Foo> build() async {
    foo = await getFoo();
    return foo;
  }

  Future<Foo> getFoo() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    return Foo(1);
  }
}
```

Implementation using Async capabilities:
**home.dart**

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Consumer(
        builder: (context, ref, _) {
          // Get the provider and watch it
          final fooAsync = ref.watch(fooControllerProvider);

          // Use .when to render UI from future
          return fooAsync.when(
            data: (foo) => Text('bar: ${foo.bar}, baz: ${foo.baz}'),
            loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
            error: (err, stack) => Text(err.toString()),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Implementation using Notifier capabilities: **home.dart**

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Consumer(
        builder: (context, ref, _) {
          // Get Foo provider and set the state of it.
          // Use it as if it were a State Provider.
          ref.watch(fooControllerProvider.notifier).foo = Foo(3);

          // Use Foo in UI (.requireValue is used to be able to listen to changes)
          final foo = ref.watch(fooControllerProvider).requireValue;
          // Use .when to render UI from future
          return Text('bar: ${foo.bar}, baz: ${foo.baz}');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## OLD ANSWER

This is a topic that I've been struggling with and thinking about a lot lately.

What I think is missing in `Remi`'s answer, is the ability to convert the `Future` data to a maniputable data.

When you're recieving `Future` data using either a [`FutureProvider`](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/future_provider/) and implementing the ui using the `when` method OR using the [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget, they both will trigger a rebuild when the remote data is received, so if you try to assign the value to your `StateProvider` it will trigger a rebuild during another rebuild which will throw.

I currently have 2 workarounds for this, and I will be updating my answer as I get more info about this.

For this example, we'll have a future provider that will wait and then return a fake data:

```dart
final _futureCounterProv = FutureProvider(
  (ref) async {
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 3),
    );
    return Random().nextInt(100);
  },
);
```

#### 1. [`Future.microtask`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/Future.microtask.html):

`Future.microtask` enables you to run an operation after the current rebuild ends.

**You have to make sure that your `StateProvider` dependencies are in a `Consumer` below the `Future.microtask` call or the `Future.microtask` will be called on each state update, which will keep reseting the `StateProvider`'s value to the future value**

```dart
// this provider will provide the current value of the counter

final _counterProv = StateProvider((ref) => 0);

class Body extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Body({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return ref.watch(_futureCounterProv).when(
      loading: () {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
      error: (error, stackTrace) {
        return Text(error.toString());
      },
      data: (data) {
        Future.microtask(
          () {
            // Assigning the future value to the `StateProvider`
            return ref.read(_counterProv.notifier).state = data;
          },
        );
        return Consumer(
          builder: (context, ref, _) {
            final count = ref.watch(_counterProv);

            return Column(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    ref
                        .read(_counterProv.notifier)
                        .update((value) => value + 1);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
                Text(
                  count.toString(),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

#### 2. [`ChangeNotifierProvider`](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/change_notifier_provider/):

`StateProvider` has 2 options to update its value: the `value` setter and the `update` method, and they both trigger a rebuild. In this workaround we want to implement a state update that does not trigger rebuild. A way to do this is by using a `ChangeNotifierProvider` instead of `StateProvider`. By using a `ChangeNotifierProvider` we can control our own update actions and call `notifyListeners` (which will trigger a rebuild) whenever we want.

**You have to make sure that your `ChangeNotifierProvider` dependencies are in a Consumer below the `updateNoNotify` call, or the `ChangeNotifierProvider`'s will keep reseting to the future's value. Also you have to make sure that all the widgets that are consuming this `ChangeNotifierProvider` are in the widget tree below the `updateNoNotify`, or they will not be rebuilt as we're not triggering a rebuild**

```dart
// the new `_counterProv`
final _counterProv = ChangeNotifierProvider(
  (ref) => _CounterNotifier(),
);

class _CounterNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _value = 0;

  int get value => _value;

  void update(int Function(int value) update) {
    _value = update(_value);
    // trigger a rebuild
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateNoNotify(int Function(int value) update) {
    _value = update(_value);
  }
}

// the ui
class Body extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Body({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return ref.watch(_futureCounterProv).when(
      loading: () {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
      error: (error, stackTrace) {
        return Text(error.toString());
      },
      data: (data) {
        // calling `updateNoNotify` which does not trigger
        // trigger rebuild as it does not call `notifyListeners`
        ref.read(_counterProv.notifier).updateNoNotify(
              (e) => data,
            );
        return Consumer(
          builder: (context, ref, _) {
            final count = ref.watch(_counterProv).value;

            return Column(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    ref.read(_counterProv.notifier).update(
                          (value) => value + 1,
                        );
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
                Text(
                  count.toString(),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

These are not the `safest` workarounds, but they are `workaround`s, and I will be updating this answer once I find a safe way to do this.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I've been struggling with this for a while now. I hope Remi decides to add safer workarounds in the future.

Comment: If you have an idea of how that would work please open an issue and share with me. I would love to help implementing such a feature and I've thought about it but I don't really know how would we achieve such a thing.

Comment: Just opened it and gave appropriate attribution. https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/2078